# approximateStreamPosition delegate

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

Is there a delegate that returns back `approximateStreamPosition` for `GCKMediaControlChannel`? I want to use this value to update the `UISlider` as a progress bar. If not, is implementing an `NSTimer` the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

This is the api to get the approximate stream position: [approximateStreamPosition](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_control_channel#a0108b52f99f28cfe6052e0486260add2)